# Duplicate leases in dhcp lease file

Tags: networking, dhcp

Sometime in my `/tmp/dhcpd.LAN.leases` file I have two or three times the same information. In this example it is not really a problem, but with hundreds of different IP address it will be.

Below an extract of my lease file:

Correct data:

```
lease 192.168.20.4 {
  starts 5 2017/10/06 09:00:44;
  ends 5 2017/10/06 09:10:44;
  cltt 5 2017/10/06 09:00:44;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 8c:4d:54:50:18:13;
  client-hostname "alexandre-laptop";
}
lease 192.168.20.2 {
  starts 5 2017/10/06 09:04:43;
  ends 5 2017/10/06 09:14:43;
  cltt 5 2017/10/06 09:04:43;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 01:23:f2:51:0f:36;
  uid "\001\000\023\362\001\0170";
}
```

Incorrect data :

```
lease 192.168.20.4 {
  starts 5 2017/10/06 09:04:57;
  ends 5 2017/10/06 09:14:57;
  cltt 5 2017/10/06 09:04:57;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 8c:4d:54:50:18:13;
  client-hostname "alexandre-laptop";
}
lease 192.168.20.4 {
  starts 5 2017/10/06 09:04:57;
  ends 5 2017/10/06 09:14:57;
  cltt 5 2017/10/06 09:04:57;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 8c:4d:54:50:18:13;
  client-hostname "alexandre-laptop";
}
lease 192.168.20.2 {
  starts 5 2017/10/06 09:09:44;
  ends 5 2017/10/06 09:19:44;
  cltt 5 2017/10/06 09:09:44;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 01:23:f2:51:0f:36;
  uid "\001\000\023\362\001\0170";
}
```

In addiction, sometime, the MAC address isn't correct, I don't if it can help. For information, the `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases` file has the same error and nothing special was add to the config file.
Did someone already have this issue?